# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset liquibase/db.changelog-1.0.xml::1.0.0::bohdan.taran:
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

```
<changeSet id="1.0.0" author="bohdan.taran">
        <createTable tableName="users">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="username" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
            </column>

            <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
            </column>

            <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR(100)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="created" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="updated" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

            <column name="status" type="VARCHAR(25)" defaultValue="ACTIVE">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>

        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

I can't find this problem in my code

Comment: Try setting the [`liquibase.sql.logLevel`](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/sql-log-level.html) to `INFO` to see the generated SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is either

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(<precision>)
```

For example `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(5)` for 5 fractional digits in the seconds field.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be specified with a [`defaultValueComputed`](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/nested-tags/column.html) attribute, instead.